# How can I take integer input dynamically and have the loop terminate on pressing enter?

Tags: c, loops, input, fgets, strtol

I need to take integer input dynamically and have it terminated as soon as user pressed enter. I never had any problem with this when I'm taking chars as input as I can easily check for newlines and each char is a single character. But here, I can't just take a char input and substract it by '0' as when I enter 10, the char value is 1 and then 0.

Here is a piece of the code I'm using :

```
int no;
while (scanf_s(" %d", &no) == 1)
    {
        printf("%d ", no);
    }
```

And here's another piece of code that I use for inputting chars, this works fine for single digit integers too :

```
char no;
while ((no=getchar()) != EOF && no != '\n')
    {
        printf(" %d ", no - '0');
    }
```

The scanf loop doesn't terminate when pressing enter but it does take the inputs all correctly. Whereas, the getchar loop terminates correctly but only stores 1 digit integers.

How can I have integer inputs be terminated at blank line user input?

Comment: Very simple: don't use `scanf`.  It's defined in terms of stream-based input; it has no concept of lines.  If you want to read and interpret lines of input, use `fgets` to read lines as strings, then process the strings.  (In doing so you'll also avoid `scanf`'s myriad other difficulties.)

Comment: When you use `%d` with `scanf`, it means, "skip leading whitespace, then read an integer consisting of one or more digits".  There's no way to turn off the "skip leading whitespace" part, which is what's causing your problem.

Comment: One thing you can do (if you want to stick with `scanf`) is change your prompt from "Enter numbers, terminated by blank line" to "Enter numbers, terminated by any non-numeric character".  If the user types `x` or something, that *will* cause `scanf` to fail and return 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use standard function `fgets` to read the input into a character array and then extract numbers using standard function `strtol`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int is_empty( const char *s )
{
    return s[strspn( s, " \t" )] == '\n';   
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 100 };
    char line[N];

    while ( fgets( line, N, stdin ) && !is_empty( line ) )
    {
        char *endptr;

        for ( const char *p = line; *p != '\n'; p = endptr )
        {
            int num = strtol( p, &endptr, 10 );
            printf( "%d ", num );

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If to input the following lines

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8
9
```

(the last line is empty that is the user just pressed Enter)

then the output will look like

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```